# Scrollbar Style

Tags: c#, wpf

How can I remove the small rectangle that appears when a horizontal and vertical scrollbar appear?

[image]

Comment: i dunno how to do it but i dun recommend it if u mean the rectangle we use to scroll up and scroll down.

Comment: You mean the white rectangle in the lower right corner?

Comment: the one on the left or right?

Comment: Is there one on the left?  I'm certain he means the one on the bottom-right corner -- it only appears when both scroll bars are present.

Comment: It's the one on the bottom right of that image.  Where the two arrows are pointing.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are using a ScrollViewer. The default template of a ScrollViewer is a Grid containing two rows and two columns. The upper left cell contains the ScrollViewer content, upper right the vertical ScrollBar, lower left the horizontal ScrollBar, and a Rectangle on the lower right cell. Please check this article: http://www.eggheadcafe.com/tutorials/aspnet/f51ddf8c-5227-4f1b-a5df-ec3d1b3439ca/styling-the-wpf-scrollviewer.aspx. You can see the default template there. You could remove the rectangle and then set either the ColumnSpan of the horizontal ScrollBar or RowSpan of the vertical ScrollBar to cover the lower right cell. Hope this helps.